# Multiple model on a view Joomla 2.5

Tags: components, joomla2.5

I write a component in joomla 2.5. I want a view use multiple model on view.

I saw [Multiple models for a view without controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804408/multiple-models-for-a-view-without-controllers).

My code: 
In class controller (Controller.php)

```
public function display($cachable = false, $urlparams = false) 
{
        AppHelper::addSubmenu(JRequest::getCmd('view', 'apps'));
        JRequest::setVar('view', JRequest::getCmd('view', 'apps'));

        $model = $this->getModel('app'); // get first model
        $view = $this->getView('apps', 'html'); // get view we want to use
        $view->setModel($model, true);  //  true is for the default model  

        $vermodel = &$this->getModel('version'); // get second model   
        $this->assignRef('version', $vermodel);

        $view->setModel($vermodel);
        var_dump($this);

        parent::display($cachable);
        return $this;
}
```

In class view (view.html.php)

```
public function display($tpl = null) 
{
        // Initialiase variables.
        $this->form = $this->get('Form');

        $this->item = $this->get('Item');
        $this->state = $this->get('State');
        $this->form2 = $this->get('Form', 'version');
       // var_dump($this->form2);

    }
```

But, view can't display to form!!!

Help me!! Thank you all.

Comment: Have you checked - is your 'Version' model available in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Insteed of:
`$this->form2 = $this->get('Form', 'version');` 
You should use: 
`$this->form2 = $this->getForm();`

For me it works. I suppose there is only one default model, thats why we should call model's function other way.